# Kmm library throwing No matching variant of was found

Tags: kotlin, maven, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created and published a KMM library to provide encryption keys. It can be found at https://github.com/abhriyaroy/KCrypt/ and I have published the same in Maven and can be found at https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.github.abhriyaroy/KCrypt/0.0.1

However, when I add the same as a library to my shared module of my sample project as

```
 sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies {
          implementation("io.github.abhriyaroy:KCrypt:0.0.1")

        }
     ..
    }
```

I get error as

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':shared:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':shared:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.github.abhriyaroy:KCrypt:0.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :shared
      > No matching variant of io.github.abhriyaroy:KCrypt:0.0.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.1', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability io.github.abhriyaroy:KCrypt:0.0.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed an API of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability io.github.abhriyaroy:KCrypt:0.0.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed an API of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64ApiElements-published' capability io.github.abhriyaroy:KCrypt:0.0.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed an API of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64MetadataElements-published' capability io.github.abhriyaroy:KCrypt:0.0.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed an API of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosX64ApiElements-published' capability io.github.abhriyaroy:KCrypt:0.0.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed an API of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosX64MetadataElements-published' capability io.github.abhriyaroy:KCrypt:0.0.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed an API of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements' capability io.github.abhriyaroy:KCrypt:0.0.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed an API of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
```

I understand something is going wrong with my library setup but I cant exactly point out what. If any kind sould would take a look and provide some insights, that would be great, thank you!

Comment: There might be an issue around how you are publishing the package, perhaps the jvm target is the only one being published whereas you need the iOS variant published as well. Off the top of my head ./gradlew publishAllPublications was something I've used in the past. Sorry I couldn't be of more help! Going through [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-library.html#publish-your-library-to-maven-central) tutorial could be of use?